# OBIEE 12c analyticsRes deployment

Tags: weblogic12c, obiee

I have custom javascript files which i have to deploy in the analyticRes folder in OBIEE 12c but I couldn't find the folder path. In OBIEE 11g it was present under /instances/instance1/bifoundation/ OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent/coreapplication_obips1/analyticsRes. What is the steps to deploy this analyticsRes in OBIEE 12c?

Answer (score 1):

You can create analyticsRes folder anywhere on OBIEE server filesystem(or at least a place OBIEE can access, can also be on a mounted shared folder) and deploy it through console to make it visible directly through analytics.

please follow this link below for step by step approach:
https://gianniceresa.com/2016/12/deploy-custom-folder-obiee-12c-analyticsres/

Answer (score 0):

In 12C it is deployed as a war. Login to obiee console(http://your_server:port/console/) and locate analyticsRes under deployment. You will get the path from here. Download the war file. Update war files with new js files and deploy again as war.

Answer (score 0):

The JAVA EE applications in OBIEE 12c are located under $ORACLE_HOME$\bi\bifoundation\jee.